# vuetify - change the v-select items depending on the state of a button

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

So I am trying to make the selector have different items depending on the state of a button that already changes between Enabled and Disabled. I tried to use v-if and v-else but I feel that is the wrong way to go about it and also was not working. I feel this is closer to what I need to use but am not sure I'm doing it right.
below is the html

```
<v-col class="col-3">
            <v-select
              :items="rulesForOptionsLevel"
              outlined
              dense
              :disabled="
                accountFeatures.optionsTrading === 'Disabled' ? true : false
              "
              v-model="accountFeatures.optionsLevel"
              @change="changeOptionsLevel"
              :menu-props="{ top: true, offsetY: true }"
              label="Level"
            ></v-select>
          </v-col>
```

this is the script below. Also in the script I made an items[] empty in data

```
methods: {
    rulesForOptionsLevel() {
    if (accountFeatures.equityTrading === "Disabled") {
      items: ["unavailable", "optionsLevel1", "optionsLevel2"];
    } else {
      items: [
        "unavailable",
        "optionsLevel1",
        "optionsLevel2",
        "optionsLevel3",
        "optionsLevel4",
        "optionsLevel5",
        "optionsLevel6",
      ];
    }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple change the `rulesForOptionsLevel` method to a computed property.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      accountFeatures: {
        optionsTrading: "disabled",
        optionsLevel: "",
        equityTrading: "Disabled"
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeOptionsLevel() {
      console.log('Options changed!');
    },
    toggleEquityTrading(){
      if(this.accountFeatures.equityTrading=="Enabled")
        this.accountFeatures.equityTrading = "Disabled";
      else
        this.accountFeatures.equityTrading = "Enabled";
      console.log(`accountFeatures.equityTrading: ${this.accountFeatures.equityTrading}`);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rulesForOptionsLevel() {
      if (this.accountFeatures.equityTrading === "Disabled")
        return ["unavailable", "optionsLevel1", "optionsLevel2"];
      else
        return [
          "unavailable",
          "optionsLevel1",
          "optionsLevel2",
          "optionsLevel3",
          "optionsLevel4",
          "optionsLevel5",
          "optionsLevel6",
        ];

    },
  },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-col class="col-3">
      <v-select :items="rulesForOptionsLevel" outlined dense :disabled="accountFeatures.optionsTrading === 'Disabled' ? true : false" v-model="accountFeatures.optionsLevel" @change="changeOptionsLevel" :menu-props="{ top: true, offsetY: true }" label="Level"></v-select>
    </v-col>
    <v-btn elevation="2" @click="toggleEquityTrading()">Toggle Equity</v-btn>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely answers the way I was trying to do it before. I found that you can do it with the way I posted above as well. Do you think that either is a better way to solve it or does it not matter which method is used?

Comment: I believe a `computed` property for populating items on runtime is the way to go. computed properties as you know are cached and only changed when the values that it binds to change. On the other hand, expressions & methods are always evaluated. Also, noticed that you created two separate arrays for maintaining the different items values, which was really uncalled for.

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining the difference and for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. No need for the function you can simply use the same method as for something like disabled. If that accountFeatures.margin equals disabled then it chooses items and if not then it chooses items2

```
] <v-select
              :items="accountFeatures.margin === 'Disabled' ? items : items2"
              outlined
              dense
              :disabled="
                accountFeatures.optionsTrading === 'Disabled' ? true : false
              "
              v-model="accountFeatures.optionsLevel"
              @change="changeOptionsLevel"
              :menu-props="{ top: true, offsetY: true }"
              label="Level"
            ></v-select>
```